# SYCL USM on integrated devices

Tags: sycl, dpc++

SYCL USM will work on discrete GPU if-and-only-if the GPU's hardware supports unified virtual address space.

What is case regarding integrated GPUs?
Can we assume that any integrated GPU supports USM?

Thanks in advance.
Ami

Answer (score 0):

Yes, integrated GPUs support Unified shared memory. Unified Shared Memory (USM) is a feature that allows both the CPU and GPU to access the same memory space directly, simplifying data sharing between the two processing units.

For more information on Unified shared memory please refer to the following sources:

- [oneAPI GPU Optimization Guide - Unified Shared Memory Allocations](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/oneapi/optimization-guide-gpu/2023-1/unified-shared-memory-allocations.html)
- [Intel oneAPI DPC++/C++ Compiler System Requirements](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/system-requirements/intel-oneapi-dpcpp-system-requirements.html)
- [oneAPI GPU Optimization Guide - Host/Device Memory, Buffer and USM](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/oneapi/optimization-guide-gpu/2023-0/host-device-memory-buffer-and-usm.html)
- A book on Data Parallel C++: *Mastering DPC++ for Programming of Heterogeneous Systems using C++ and SYCL* - James Reinders